# How to copy child node from one node to other node?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treenode

My `JTree` has two nodes say 'A' and 'B'. A has 3 child nodes. I want to add one of child node of A to B without removing from Node 'A'. so that same child node will appears in both nodes (A and B).

How this is done?

Here is snippet of how i am adding selected node from one parent to other parent node.

```
 DefaultMutableTreeNode node;
    TreePath[] paths = tree.getSelectionPaths();
    if(paths != null){
        for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
          node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (paths[i].getLastPathComponent());
          stitchedNode.add(node);
          String expansionState = getExpansionState();  
          model.reload();
          setExpansionState(expansionState);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share you code where you want to implement this?

Comment: 1) From the details of [`MutableTreeNode.setParent(MutableTreeNode)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/MutableTreeNode.html#setParent-javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode-) it appears that the tree nodes can only have a single parent, mimicking that components (like any `JComponent`) can have only a single parent. That does not stop the programmer from adding a single object to a tree more than once, but raises the question of why the app. would need to do that. Can you explain further, using more descriptive words than `A` or `B`? ..

Comment: .. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) of the current code.

Comment: @AndrewThompson My application requires to have node with multiple parents. Actually I have list of images with ImageListNode, which when stitched with another image should appear in other node say StitchedImageNode without being removed from ImageListNode.

Comment: *"which when stitched with another image"* What do you mean by 'stitched'? Are the images separate frames of an animation? Different parts (or sub-views) of a map? ..

Comment: Then have a model in which your nodes have multiple parents, and "map" it to a `Jtree` so that some of the nodes uses the same node model to be able to show the same datum. An Model-Vivew-Controller architecture is a good choice for that.

Comment: @AndrewThompson each node represents a certain images. I have a separate frame for image stitch. Selection of image node just provides the path of image. ones image manipulation is done it will be added with another node(stitchedNode) but a copy of the same will be with imageListNode.